# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>

Tags: sql

I am executing an update query

```
begin

 update active_cus 
 set Global_indicator = 'Y' where cust_id = '3311' ;

end;
```

I get the sql error

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of
>   the following:
>
> ;   The symbol
>   ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work without the BEGIN ... END; ?
If your script is longer than the sample you posted, another END; may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

begin
update set ... where ...;
end
commit;

this works for me